# Need to get element id from .net COM winform control

Tags: c#, html, .net, com, user-controls

I have created a .NET UserControl and exposed as a COM Control. It can be used in a html web page with object tag

Html Object tag looks like

```
<OBJECT id=control01 class=MyControl classid=clsid:C2A76664-69FA-45C8-B052-7322B14CB206></OBJECT>
```

And my .Net Control code look like below

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual),
ComVisible(true),
Guid("C2A76664-69FA-45C8-B052-7322B14CB206"),
ProgId("MyControl")]
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
        private void MyControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Need to get object id here "id=control01"

        }
}
```

When i load this control in a html page and called in browser. I should get the element id in my control class either in load event or constructor

Please anyone help me on how to get the html element id in .NET control class.

Comment: Why do it as a COM object? Why not a .NET UserControl?

Comment: Actually it is a .NET UserControl only. To expose function and properties in unmanaged world. i made it as COM

Comment: OK. What have you tried? What failed?

Comment: I am using Componet.site in the construtor to get the dom object model of html page. But this gives me the entire object model. i dont need the entire object model. i need only the dom element of this object. 
Thanks for helping. sorry for delayed reply